# How To transform xml to soap request

Tags: xml, soap, mule

I am very new to soap. I would like to transform the following xml to a soap message. How do i do this? I am using Mule Anypoint studio

```
<SalesOrder>
  <salesOrderId>00001-2-3</salesOrderId>
  <saleName>Car Sale</saleName>
  <status>processing</status>
</SalesOrder>
<SalesOrder2>
  <salesOrderId>00004-5-6</salesOrderId>
  <saleName>House Sale</saleName>
  <status>processing</status>
</SalesOrder2>
```

Comment: You XML is not valid There must be a root element.. <SalesOrder> and <SalesOrder2> are 2 different root and should comes under a common roots like <Sales> etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using XSLT - Mule comes packaged with an XSLT Transformer component. You can find more specific guidance on the transformation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182786/xml-to-soap-transformation). Hope that helps.